# Lightview not working in one of my website

Tags: jquery-ui, lightbox, jquery-ui-tabs

I tried a test file which is working but this file isn't. I also tried validating from w3c and it showed no errors. I also tried pasting

outside jquery ui tabs but still didn't worked out. Could there be any conflict between plugins. And also when i gave absolute path for demo file it worked while relative path didn't.  Here's the two file:

This one is working (demo file)-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script> <!-- optional --> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/excanvas/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/spinners/spinners.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightview/lightview.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightview/lightview.css" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main-style.css" />
</head>


<body>

<a href='img/colorful-abstract.jpg' class='lightview' data-lightview-group='example'>
    <img src='img/thumbs colorful-abstract.jpg' alt=''/>
  </a>
</body>
</html>





Where as this original ones isn't working-

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Rahul Dagli's Portfolio Website</title>

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!--lightview-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spinners/spinners.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightview/lightview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas/excanvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>


    <!--CSS-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navigation-menu.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main-style.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightview/lightview.css" />

</head>



<body>
    <!--main navigation-->
    <nav>
      <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="portfolio"><a href="" title="Portfolio"></a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="" title="About"></a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="" title="Contact"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


    <!--main content-->
    <div id="sections">

        <!--Portfolio page starts-->

        <section id="section-portfolio">


            <header>
                <hgroup>
                  <h1>Rahul Dagli</h1>
                    <h2> Web Designer</h2>
                </hgroup>
                <p>Welcome to my online portfolio. Take a look at my work and find out who I am.</p>
            </header>


            <!--Tabbed Image Gallery-->
            <div id="portfolio-list">
                    <div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Graphic design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Web design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Flash</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-3">3d</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div id="tabs-1">
                         <ul>
                            <li></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="tabs-2">
                        </div>

                        <div id="tabs-3">
                        </div>

                    </div>

            </div>



        </section>
        <!--Portfolio page ends-->

        <!--About page starts-->
        <section id="section-about">
        </section>
        <!--About page ends-->

        <!--Contact page starts-->
        <section id="section-contact">
        </section>
        <!--Contact page ends-->

    </div>
<a href='img/colorful-abstract.jpg' class='lightview' data-lightview-group='example'>
    <img src='img/thumbs-colorful-abstract.jpg' alt=''/>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example folder in the download you could use to start from, it shows a proper installation. Once that works, Lightview should work in the tabs as well.

Also keep in mind that all the Lightview related includes on your page are absolute, not relative like your other includes. So it could be that the files aren't where you expect them to be.